# Why hit box doesn't move when using collision source with deform?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision

Initial state
[image: Initial state]

end state

[image]

The box moved, but the hit box doesn't move, so the softbody hit the air.
However, if I change the box's rigidbody>collisions>source from `deform` to `base` or change `Shape` to anything like cone or box other than convex hull and mesh, the hit box moved.

My question is, what's wrong with the deform? why hitbox doesn't move with it? And why when I change shape to cone, box, etc. It's moving again?

Download source file
[image]